# Computing prediction interval on discrete dynamical system forecast

Tags: confidence-interval, linear-dynamical-system

Apologies if this is a basic question. Let's say I have a dynamical process $x_{n+1}=Ax_n+\varepsilon_n,$ where $A$ is an $m\times m$ matrix and $\varepsilon_n=(\varepsilon_{1,n},\varepsilon_{2,n},\ldots,\varepsilon_{m,n})$ with $\varepsilon_{i,n}\sim N(\mu_i,\sigma_i)$ for each $n$ and $1\leq i\leq m$. Here both $\mu_i$ and $\sigma_i$ are known. What I would like to do is compute a confidence bound on the forecast error, $||A^{n+1} x_0-x_{n+1}||$, given $A$ and some initial condition $x_0$. What I have worked out so far is that we can write
$$x_{n+1}=A^{n+1}x_0+A^n \varepsilon_0+ A^{n-1} \varepsilon_1 + \dotsm + A\varepsilon_{n-1}+\varepsilon_n,$$
so
$$||x_{n+1}-A^{n+1}x_0||=||A^n \varepsilon_0+ A^{n-1} \varepsilon_1 + \dotsm + A\varepsilon_{n-1}+\varepsilon_n||.$$
Therefore, if $\sigma_1$ is the largest singular value of $A$,

$$||x_{n+1}-A^{n+1}x_0||\leq \sum_{i=0}^n \sigma_1^{n-i} ||\varepsilon_i||.$$

If I could put a confidence upper bound on this sum, then I would be done, but I am unsure how to go about doing that. From my reading it seems that each of $||\varepsilon_i||$ would have a noncentered chi distribution, but I am unsure how the summation would affect this. If this is problem is intractable or extremely difficult, we could also make the simplifying assumption that $\sigma_1\leq 1$, so that we just need to bound the upper bound $\sum_{i=0}^n ||\varepsilon_i||$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the fact that the $\varepsilon_i$ are random variables, so we should take the expected values in the inequality you gave. Otherwise I suspect there's no way to bound the $\varepsilon_i$ further.

So, taking the expectation on both sides of the inequality, we get
\begin{align}
E(||x_{n+1}−A^{n+1}x_0||) &\leq E(\sum_{i=0}^n\sigma_1^{n−i}||\varepsilon_i||) \\
&=  \sum_{i=0}^n\sigma_1^{n−i} E(||\varepsilon_i||) \\
\end{align}

I assume you are using $L^2$ norm. Then, because of Jensen's inequality, we have

\begin{align}
E(||\varepsilon_i||) &= E( \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^m \varepsilon_{ki}^2}) \\
&\leq \sum_{k=1}^m \sqrt{E(\varepsilon_{ki}^2)} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^m \sqrt{\mu_k^2 + \sigma_k^2}
\end{align}

Plugging this in the inequality above, we get

\begin{align}
E(||x_{n+1}−A^{n+1}x_0||) &\leq  \sum_{k=1}^m \sqrt{\mu_k^2 + \sigma_k^2} \sum_{i=0}^n\sigma_1^{n−i}\\
\end{align}

And you can simplify the geometric sum even further.